# how to create index by using dynamic sql?

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper, plsql-package

----------- it is giving below error ,where i did mistake ---------------

```
declare l1 integer;
    begin execute immediate q '!
      begin
        execute immediate ' CREATE INDEX S_ACCNT_ATT_P1 ON S_ACCNT_ATT(ROW_ID) PARALLEL 4 ';
        execute immediate ' CREATE INDEX S_ACCNT_ATT_U1 ON S_ACCNT_ATT(PAR_ROW_ID, FILE_NAME, FILE_EXT, CONFLICT_ID) PARALLEL 4 ';
        execute immediate '
    select 1 from  dual '
        into :l1;
      end;!' using out l1;
    end;
```

------- error -------------------
ORA-06550: line 2, column 27:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "!
begin
execute immediate " when expecting one of the following:

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the incorrect q-quoting syntax. That is causing the error you're seeing.

```
DECLARE
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE q '!BEGIN NULL; END;!';
END;
/

Error report -
ORA-06550: line 3, column 23:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "!BEGIN NULL; END;!" when expecting one of the following:

   . ( * @ % & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
   return returning <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <>
   and or like like2 like4 likec between into using || multiset
   bulk member submultiset
The symbol "*" was substituted for "!BEGIN NULL; END;!" to continue.
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

There should be no space between the `q` and the `'`:

```
DECLARE
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE q'!BEGIN NULL; END;!';
END;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Answer (score 0):

How/where exactly did you run that piece of code? I tested it on TOAD and SQL*Plus in Oracle 11g.

Sample table:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE s_accnt_att
  2  (
  3     row_id        NUMBER,
  4     par_row_id    NUMBER,
  5     file_name     NUMBER,
  6     file_ext      NUMBER,
  7     conflict_id   NUMBER
  8  );

Table created.
```

Procedure:

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
SQL>
SQL> DECLARE
  2     l1  INTEGER;
  3  BEGIN
  4     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE q'[
  5        begin
  6          execute immediate ' CREATE INDEX S_ACCNT_ATT_P1 ON S_ACCNT_ATT ( ROW_ID ) PARALLEL 4 ';
  7          execute immediate ' CREATE INDEX S_ACCNT_ATT_U1 ON S_ACCNT_ATT ( PAR_ROW_ID , FILE_NAME , FILE_EXT , CONFLICT_ID ) PARALLEL 4 ';
  8          execute immediate ' select 1 from dual '
  9          into :l1;
 10        end;
 11        ]'
 12        USING OUT l1;
 13
 14     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('L1 = ' || l1);
 15  END;
 16  /
L1 = 1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Seems to be OK.

---

As your target database is **19c**, I tried it there as well; no problem.

```
SQL> select banner from v$version;

BANNER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production

SQL> DECLARE
  2     l1  INTEGER;
  3  BEGIN
  4     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE q'[
  5            begin
  6              execute immediate ' CREATE INDEX S_ACCNT_ATT_P1 ON S_ACCNT_ATT ( ROW_ID ) PARALLEL 4 ';
  7              execute immediate ' CREATE INDEX S_ACCNT_ATT_U1 ON S_ACCNT_ATT ( PAR_ROW_ID , FILE_NAME , FILE_EXT , CONFLICT_ID ) PARALLEL 4 ';
  8              execute immediate ' select 1 from dual '
  9              into :l1;
 10           end;
 11           ]'
 12        USING OUT l1;
 13
 14     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('L1 = ' || l1);
 15  END;
 16  /
L1 = 1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Therefore, maybe it is about your migration tool (which one is it) that **doesn't recognize the q-quoting mechanism**. If that's so, don't use it and *double* single quotes instead:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     l1  INTEGER;
  3  BEGIN
  4     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '
  5            begin
  6              execute immediate '' CREATE INDEX S_ACCNT_ATT_P1 ON S_ACCNT_ATT ( ROW_ID ) PARALLEL 4 '';
  7              execute immediate '' CREATE INDEX S_ACCNT_ATT_U1 ON S_ACCNT_ATT ( PAR_ROW_ID , FILE_NAME , FILE_EXT , CONFLICT_ID ) PARALLEL 4 '';
  8              execute immediate '' select 1 from dual ''
  9              into :l1;
 10           end;
 11           '
 12        USING OUT l1;
 13
 14     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('L1 = ' || l1);
 15  END;
 16  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: I am running this code in my migration tool which from  database 11g to database 19c. it is still giving me same error even  code is right according to me. what can be the reason behind this?